# How to scale video and then overlay an image using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, watermark

I'm using a website script that has been created by someone who unfortunately doesn't provide any help on this subject.

Here is the piece of code:

```
$com=$global_settings["ffmpeg_path"]." -i \"".$apath."\" -vcodec libx264 -strict -2  -t ".$duration."  -vf 'movie=".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].site_root."/content/watermark-video.png [wm];[in][wm] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 [out]' -vf scale=498:-1 ".$flv_path;
```

It's supposed to do what I need which is described in title of this post, but it doesn't. It scales video, but doesn't apply a png watermark. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter_complex` because the `overlay` filter uses more than one input. Your generic command line would look like:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -filter_complex "movie=<path to png>[image],[0:v]scale=h:w[scaled],[scaled][image]overlay[out]" -vcodec libx264 -strict -2 -t <duration> -map [out] <outfile>
```

More Specific for your case:

```
if($global_settings["ffmpeg_watermark"])
{
    $com=$global_settings["ffmpeg_path"]." -i \"".$apath."\" -vcodec libx264 -strict -2 -t ".$duration." -filter_complex 'movie=".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].site_root."/content/water‌​‌​mark-video.png [wm];[0:v]scale=498:-1[scaled];[scaled][wm] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 [out]' -map [out] " .$flv_path;
}
else
{
    $com=$global_settings["ffmpeg_path"]." -i \"".$apath."\" -vcodec libx264 -strict -2 -t ".$duration." ".$flv_path;
}
exec($com);
```

Comment: Actually, this is the correct forum for ffmpeg cli questions. And the reason the OP's command doesn't work is because the 2nd `vf` overrides the first.

Comment: Would it be possible for someone show me how to implement the correct command in the code I have: if($global_settings["ffmpeg_watermark"]) { $com=$global_settings["ffmpeg_path"]." -i \"".$apath."\" -vcodec libx264 -strict -2 -t ".$duration." -vf 'movie=".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].site_root."/content/water‌​mark-video.png [wm];[in][wm] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 [out]' -vf scale=498:-1 ".$flv_path; } else { $com=$global_settings["ffmpeg_path"]." -i \"".$apath."\" -vcodec libx264 -strict -2 -t ".$duration." ".$flv_path; } } exec($com);

Comment: Updated answere more specific for your case.

Comment: @Rens Thank you! Let me try, and I'll get back with the result...